# Convert a console program to a dll and preserve arguments

Tags: c#, dll

I have a dll that used to be a console program, it still has code to use "static Main(string[] args)"  is there a way to pass args when I load the DLL?

I'm using

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("App.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("App.LoadFile");
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type,new string[] { filepath });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Main` method will not be called just by loading the assembly in your 2nd program.  You just need to invoke the `Main` method on the `type` you have above.

Here's how you can call the static `Main` method from your  code...

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("App.dll");
var type = assembly.GetType("App.LoadFile");

var args = new string[] { filepath };

var main = type.GetMethod("Main", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
    );

main.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I was missing.

Comment: However the parent process doesn't close when I close the DLL form.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the program to exit when this other "Main" method is finished running?  It sounds like you just need to call `Application.Exit()` when you are done.